# Cargo start up error

Tags: apache, maven, tomcat, cargo, maven-cargo

I am running 'mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true' command for a web application. but it gives following error. I set the catalina home as an environment variable. i am using maven 3.1.1 version. Please help me

```
 FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports i
nitialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Addres
s already in use
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:star
t (start-container) on project RCMigrationWebApp: Execution start-container of g
oal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:start failed: Failed to start t
he Tomcat 7.x container. Deployable [http://localhost:8080/cargocpc/index.html]
failed to finish deploying within the timeout period [120000]. The Deployable st
ate is thus unknown. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: The timeout is too short. Check why the deployment takes such a long time. Try it manually and check log files etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to kill any process running at 8080, looks like the port is already in use..
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use

Answer (score 0):

Port in use. Run `netstat -bv` if you are using `Windows`. You will get to know which process is holding up the port. With your stackTrace, it looks very obvious.

Let me know if it helps.